# handle responses of multiple parallel ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 parallel jQuery ajax requests towards my service (jsonp), and everything works fine until the data is returned from service and needed to be displayed to user. I'm not able to handle responses, since they all arrive in interval of just a few milliseconds, and they call the same jsonp callback method.

What I want to do is update data box when each one of ajax request complete its job.

Code example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://link/service?source=1',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   jsonpCallback: 'asyncPrint'
   complete: function(data) {
      console.log("completed");
   }
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://link/service?source=2',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   jsonpCallback: 'asyncPrint'
   complete: function(data) {
      console.log("completed");
   }
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://link/service?source=3',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   jsonpCallback: 'asyncPrint'
   complete: function(data) {
      console.log("completed");
   }
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://link/service?source=4',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   jsonpCallback: 'asyncPrint'
   complete: function(data) {
      console.log("completed");
   }
});
```

In other file I have implemented asyncPrint method:

```
function asyncPrint(data) {
   if(data == undefined) return;

   //Populate sourceMedia with data from all sources
   sourceMedia[data.list[0].source] = data;

   //Do something with arrived data
   goThroughArrivedData(data);
}
```

P.S. 
I've tried with $.when(), but than it wait for all ajax requests to complete, which is unacceptable, since one of the ajax calls can take more than 30 seconds.

Comment: *since they all arrive in interval of just a few milliseconds* this is where I'm stucked. How is this a problem?

Comment: All 4 requests are executed at same time, and the time of execution is for 3 requests almost the same (arount 900 miliseconds)...  I thought it might be a problem, because all 3 ajax calls are trying to access the same JS method at the same time.

Comment: This should not be a problem at all. Because at some point of the process flow you will encounter that a function call is *blocking* and thus the subsequent execution will be waiting for that call to finish. Meaning that, if you, for example, add dom-elements to a common parent they will be inserted just fine. Maybe in an unpredictable manner, but surely the will be added.

Comment: Ok fixed,

I've assigned to each ajax request a unique callback method name, and in those methods I encapsulate main method for execution (asyncPrint(data)) ...

It seems that jQuery puts jsonp callbacks in an array of callbacks, and on callback call, it removes it from callback list (since it is executed), causing, in my case, other ajax requests fail due to callback method missing. I haven't dig in into jQuery, but this sounds like reasonable jQuery execution flow. Thanks @Yoshi for your responses.